# Open CDialog from Java using JNI

Tags: dll, debugging, java-native-interface, cdialog

I have an application that needs to open a CDialog written inside a DLL. The problem is that when DoModal() is called inside the DLL, the program crashes with: "Debug Assertion Failed!". Does anyone have any idea how can i get the CDialog opened? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At this point you would probably need to do some debugging at the C++ level - there isn't really enough to go on here to tell what might be going wrong. The kind of things you need to look at are what the debug assertion was that failed, the stack trace at the time, what it was trying todo, and what caused the crash. A debug assertion by itself is not a crash, although it is a good clue, and the cause of the failed assertion may also be the cause of the crash.